# reverse slice of string [x:y:-1] prints blank

Tags: python, string, slice

I have strings representing a DNA sequence and its complement and I am searching them for reverse palindromes.

The slice

```
seq1[i:z]
```

works great, but

```
seq2[i:z:-1]
```

prints nothing and returns nothing.

Further, `seq[i:z][::-1]` works fine in all cases, but is this normal for string slices?

Comment: what is the actual problem? What you need excatly?

Comment: Show us the values of `seq1`, `seq2`, `i`, and `z`

Answer (score 6):

If you're stepping backwards through an iterable (i.e. `step` is negative), you need to swap the order of the `start` and `end` values so that `start > end`:

```
>>> seq = 'abcde'
>>> seq[1:4:-1]
''
>>> seq[4:1:-1]
'edc'
```

Otherwise, you'll get back an empty string (or empty list or empty tuple).

Do note that `seq[4:1:-1]` *does not* produce the same result as `seq[1:4][::-1]` however. The former starts at index `4`, moves backwards and stops before index `1`, whereas the latter starts at index `1`, moves forward, stops before index `4` and then reverses the slice.

Instead we have for an iterable `seq` and for integers `i < j`:

```
seq[i:j][::-1] == seq[j-1:i-1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For palindroms,

```
a=input("entry something: ")
if a==a[::-1]:
    print ("It is a palindrom.")
```

So if *a's* reverse equal to *a*, it will print its a palindrom.